# Connection over ftp with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have to connect to one server over ftp and download a zip file.

This is what I have tried without any luck:

```
$url = $server_file = '/expiring_service_auctions.csv.zip';
$target = $local_file = 'godaddy.zip';
$out = 'godaddy.csv';


$ftp_server = 'ftp.godaddy.com'; //'208.109.78.100'
$ftp_user_name = 'auctions';
$ftp_user_pass = ''; //no pass


// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);

try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

What to do? What to do?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages ?

Comment: Somehow I doubt that godaddy is going to be letting this file be in the root of  THEIR filesystem. Are you sure you've got the correct source path for the file? It's probably NOT going to be just `/expiring.csv.zip`, and something more like `/home/username/expiring.csv.zip`.

Comment: @MarcB Logging into their FTP directly, it's there in the root. Probably because of the `auctions` username.

Comment: @pmagunia When trying to see the files I am getting: Boolean(False), the rest of the script, is loading without any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I logged into the FTP server, it suggested using PASV. Add this after your login line:

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```